# Find highest consecutive salary from given collection

Tags: c#, moving-average

e.g. We have a collection

```
[ 
  {1,' A,' 100},
  {2, 'X', 200},
  {3, 'D', 300},
  {5, 'B', 300},
  {6, 'Z', 300},
  {7, 'G', 300}, 
]
```

likewise.

I start with the last object first then If my limit is `3` then I'll pick the *last three* to find the average of `int` num.

In this `1, 2, 3` then `2, 3, 4` but `4` is missing from the collection then I will skip this and pick `3, 4, 5` same I need to skip this finally I will start `5, 6, 7` wise I will go `N` record.

Then I need to pick a set that contains the *highest average* of the number.

Comment: Please show a [mcve] of your C# code.

Comment: Are you looking for *moving average*? `Avg(100, 200, 300) = 200` then `Avg(200, 300, 300) = 267`, `Avg(300, 300, 300) = 300` etc.

Comment: Yes @DmitryBychenko

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for a *moving average*? Having a *window* of size == `3` you compute averages of `0..2` items, then of `1..3` items, etc:

```
  (1, 'A', 100), -> not enough data to compute moving average
  (2, 'X', 200), -> not enough data to compute moving average
  (3, 'D', 300), -> (100 + 200 + 300) / 3 == 200
  (5, 'B', 300), -> (200 + 300 + 300) / 3 == 267
  (6, 'Z', 300), -> (300 + 300 + 300) / 3 == 300
  (7, 'G', 300), -> (300 + 300 + 300) / 3 == 300
```

If it's your task, then you can do it as follow:

```
  private static IEnumerable<(T item, double average)> MovingAverage<T>(
    IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, double> selector, int windowSize) {

    if (source is null)
      throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
    if (selector is null)
      throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(selector));
    if (selector is null)
      throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(selector));
    if (windowSize <= 0)
      throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(windowSize));

    double total = 0.0;
    var priors = new Queue<double>();

    foreach (var item in source) {
      double value = selector(item);
      priors.Enqueue(value);
      total += value;   
  
      while (priors.Count > windowSize)
        total -= priors.Dequeue();

      if (priors.Count == windowSize)    
        yield return (item, total / windowSize);
    }
  }
```

Demo:

```
var data = new (int id, char name, int value)[] { 
  (1, 'A', 100),
  (2, 'X', 200),
  (3, 'D', 300),
  (5, 'B', 300),
  (6, 'Z', 300),
  (7, 'G', 300),
};
      
var result = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, 
   MovingAverage(data, item => item.value, 3)
  .Select(item => $"{item.item} :: {Math.Round(item.average)}"));

Console.Write(result);
```

Output:

```
(3, D, 300) :: 200   // (100 + 200 + 300) / 3
(5, B, 300) :: 267   // (200 + 300 + 300) / 3
(6, Z, 300) :: 300   // (300 + 300 + 300) / 3
(7, G, 300) :: 300   // (300 + 300 + 300) / 3
```

Having moving average computed, you can easily obtain max record from it with a help of *Linq*:

```
    using System.Linq;

    ...

    var max = MovingAverage(data, item => item.value, 3)
      .MaxBy(pair => pair.average);   
        
    Console.WriteLine($"Max: {max.item} :: {max.average}");
```

Output:

```
Max: (6, Z, 300) :: 300
```

which means that max moving average (that is `300`) group starts from `(6, Z, 300)` item.

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GKN6qM)